# Convert time to 24 hours format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, hour

How can I isolate and convert the local time format in JavaScript's `new Date()` to a 24 hour format?

Example: `2016-09-22T23:21:56.027Z` just becomes `22:56` in local time.

Comment: Can you describe in words how you would solve this problem? (This would be to determine whether you understand the problem itself.)

Comment: Here are useful answers for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347521/change-time-format-to-24-hours-in-javascript

Answer (score 38):

```
new Date("2000-01-01 10:30 AM").getHours() // 10
```

This *is* 24 hours:

```
new Date("2000-01-01 10:30 PM").getHours() // 22
```

If you want a more general thing:

```
function get_hours(time_string) {
    return new Date("2000-01-01 " + time_string).getHours() // 22
}
```

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Sorry, but this does not right pad the hours if the hour is a single digit. That is, `new Date('2019-01-01 00:00').getHours() === 0`

Answer (score 6):

**In moment.js** you can do:

```js
theDate.format("H:MM")
```

Take a look here for more details: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: It requires moment.js to include. without it does not work

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja how can it , Can you send code in comment.