# change time format to 24 hours in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a time format like: 12/16/2011 3:49:37 PM and I got this format by:

```
var newDate = new Date(timeFromat);
timeFormat = newDate.toLocaleString();
```

My actual format was GMT and I converted it to my bowers time by using the code above.

and I want to change it to 24h time format so I want this date to be changed like: 12/16/2011 15:49:37 and I want to do it in javascript.

Thats what I did

```
var firstPartOftimeFormat = timeFormat.substring(0,9);
var secondPartOftimeFormat = timeFormat.substring(10,20);
```

but it does not work when the date format is like: 3/16/2011. but the following part works.

```
var time = $("#starttime").val();
var hours = Number(secondPartOftimeFormat.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(secondPartOftimeFormat.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM = secondPartOftimeFormat.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
if(AMPM == "PM" && hours<12) hours = hours+12;
if(AMPM == "AM" && hours==12) hours = hours-12;
var sHours = hours.toString();
var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
if(hours<10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
if(minutes<10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
alert(sHours + ":" + sMinutes);
```

Can you suggest other approach?

thanks

Comment: Various solutions to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Why are you using `toLocaleString` (which behaves differently for different locales) when you want a specific output format? I'd use a manual formatting here.

Comment: Do not set any time format javascript `Date` by default return time in 24hr.

Comment: Thanks, but my time format was GMT and I converted it to my browers time by var newDate = new Date(timeFromat); timeFormat = newDate.toLocaleString(); and the time is a past time.

Answer (score 69):

use `dateObj.toLocaleString([locales[, options]])`

**Option 1** - Using locales

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-GB'));
```

**Option 2** - Using options

```
var options = { hour12: false };
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', options));
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work by now for some reason, it still returns time in 12 hours format.

Comment: it should be selected answer!

Comment: I mistakenly first tried `date.toLocaleString(options)`, which didn't work but didn't fail, but then changed it to `date.toLocaleString('en-US', options)`, which did work.

Answer (score 20):

`hourCycle: 'h23'` is Perfect

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/12425695/luis-serrano

```
new Date().toLocaleString('ru-RU', {
    timeZone: 'Europe/Moscow',
    hourCycle: 'h23',
    year: "numeric",
    month: "2-digit",
    day: "2-digit",
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
    second: "2-digit"
});
```

Comment: I think nowadays you use `hour12`, which is a boolean. So it would be something like:  ```hour12: false,
  year: "numeric",
  month: "2-digit", etc etc etc```

Answer (score 12):

Using some resources
[Date/toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)<sup><sub>MDN</sub></sup>
[Date/toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)<sup><sub>MDN</sub></sup>

```js
const lang = navigator.language || navigator.languages[0];
const date = new Date();
const date_locale = date.toLocaleDateString(lang, {
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  year: 'numeric'
});
const time_locale = date.toLocaleTimeString(lang);

const formatted = `${date_locale} ${time_locale}`;
console.log(formatted)
```

above we deduce the current language from the [Window's Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator) object.
In case `lang` ends up being `undefined` it's perfectly fine, defaults will be used.

To **force a desired format**, you can manually set `lang` to i.e: `'en-US'`, `'eu'`, `'en-GB'`, `'de-DE'`, `'hr-HR'` etc...

Here's an example for time:

```js
const date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US')) // 12h
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')) // 24h
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString())        // Default
```

Answer (score 10):

To get 24hrs format:

```js
const date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString([], {
    hourCycle: 'h23',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit'
}));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below code to get 24hrs format

```
new Date("3/16/2011 3:49:37 PM").getHours() // 15
new Date("3/16/2011 3:49:37 PM").getMinutes() // 49
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
// British English uses day-month-year order and 24-hour time without AM/PM
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-GB'));
// → "20/12/2012 03:00:00"
```

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Its Perfectly Working fine for me.
It gives 24 hrs time format

```
var Date= new Date();

var TimeFormat= date.toLocaleString('en-GB');
```

Your answer will be
**Fri Dec 14 2018 18:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

Answer (score 2):

```js
new Date().toLocaleTimeString('fa-IR', { hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' })
```

this is how it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It's Working fine for me. It gives 24 hrs time format.

```
let time = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'Europe/London' }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function displayTime() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var currentHour = currentDate.getHours();
        var currentMinute = currentDate.getMinutes();
        var currentSecond = currentDate.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('timeDiv').innerHTML = 'Hour: ' + currentHour + ' Minute: ' + currentMinute + ' Second: ' + currentSecond;
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        window.setInterval('displayTime()', 1000);
    }
    // -->
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my time format was GMT and I converted it to my browers time by var newDate = new Date(timeFromat);
timeFormat = newDate.toLocaleString(); and the time is a past time. but your solution does not work. since When I apply getHours() in timeFormat = newDate.toLocaleString().getHourse(); it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.getHours());
alert(d.getMinutes());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+3","dd.MM.yy k:mm:ss"));
```

try in format k:m:s insted of hh:mm:ss to

[Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

[Tutorial Class SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

const number = moment("02:00 PM", ["h:mm A"]).format("HH:mm");
console.log(number);

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. de-DE can be replaced with any language string like us-GB , nl-NL, etc.

```
function showTime() {
    const date = new Date();
    let time = date.toLocaleTimeString('de-DE', {
        hour12: false,
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute:'2-digit',
        second:'2-digit'
    });
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
}

showTime();
```