# change time format in 24 hour format

Tags: javascript, php, time

I need to subtract time on my WebApp and upload it to the database. so I want to use a 24 hour time so i wont get negative values. so here is my Code
    I have a time format like these : 08:08:AM
    I want to convert these time in 24 hour time format

```
Time format like these : 08:08:AM
I want to change these time in 24 hour time format.
```

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788705/convert-time-to-24-hours-format-in-javascript

Comment: Are you sure it is `08:08:AM` or `08:08 AM`?

Comment: now it is working @Thamizhan

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', '08:08 AM');
echo $date->format('H:i:s');   // 08:08:00

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i A', '08:08 PM');
echo $date->format('H:i:s');  // 20:08:00
```

Comment: Please be sure to vote up my answer and accept it if it solves your purpose. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is `08:08 AM` instead of `08:08:AM`, this will work for you:

```
echo date("H:i:s",strtotime("08:08 AM")); //08:08:00
echo date("H:i:s",strtotime("08:08 PM")); //20:08:00
```

But if it is `08:08:AM`, you need to remove that `:` before `AM` first and then apply the time:

```
$time_original = "08:08:AM";
$time = preg_replace("/(\d+):(\d+):(AM|PM)/", "$1:$2 $3", $time_original);
echo date("H:i:s",strtotime($time)); //08:08:00
```