# Format hour to 24h

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I've got an hour in a string format like this : 14:00:00.000
I want to convert it in a nicer format : 14h

I try to use react-moment for this, with

```
<Moment format="hh:mm:ss.a">"14:00:00.000"</Moment>
```

But it doesn't work. Any good practice?

Comment: What about using `format="hh[h]"`?

Comment: Still invalid format

Comment: Consider reading their documentation? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788705/convert-time-to-24-hours-format-in-javascript

Comment: I think, I cannot use moment with an hour format, it expects a string in a format with a date like this "2013-02-08T09   "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`momentjs` is in legacy state and explained in detail in the [project status page.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Their recommended alternative is [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/).

To format it like you have specified, simply use the [toFormat()](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=toformat) method. Included in that link is a list of tokens you can use to help format it to exactly how you'd like it.

The following formats it like you have asked: `14h`

```js
DateTime.now().toFormat("HH'h'")
```

Comment: Thanks for the Luxon recommendation. In my case, this works : DateTime.fromISO(schedule.scheduleEndTime).toFormat("HH'h'mm")