# Input Type = "time" 24 hour format <input type="time" class="form-control" ng-model="c.eachDayTime['Time']">

Tags: php, html, css, angularjs

I initialized c.eachDayTime['Time']= new Date(2021, 1, 24, 18, 0, 0, 0);
But in the input field it showing as 06:00 PM But I want output as 18:00

if my computer is in 12 hour format the time I can able to enter range from 0 - 12
But I want to make the system irrespective of system local time.
If my system it is in 12 hour format I can able to enter time in 24 hour format 0 - 24

can anyone help me to do this????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert time to 24 hours format in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788705/convert-time-to-24-hours-format-in-javascript)

Comment: some suggestions : i dont think the css tag is needed here, also add the javascript tag