# how can I show time like whatsApp chat

Tags: javascript, firebase, datetime

I build chat application using firestore as backend. Now I want when some user send a message there should be a time of that message.

there is some error ie.

> react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {seconds, nanoseconds}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14887:1)

> react_devtools_backend.js:4012 The above error occurred in the  component:

I wrote this code to send data on firebase

```js
messages: arrayUnion({
  id: uuid(),
  text,
  img: downloadURL,
  senderId: currentUser.uid,
  date: Timestamp.now(),
  // time: Date().get
});
```

and when a fetch data from firebase

```js
<div>
  <p>
    {message.text}
    <span>{message.date && <span>{message.date}</span>}</span>
  </p>
  {message.img && <img src={message.img} alt="" />}
</div>;
```

I want to show message time with message.
**Note:** I map through messages like :

```
messages.map(message => {})
```

Comment: Note: if I remove this span my entire app working fine

Answer (score 0):

Note: Edited

In your original code, you have:

```
message.date && <span>{message.date}</span>
```

But according to the error message, `message.date` is a JavaScript object which React does not know how to display. If your `message` object comes directly from Firestore, `message.date` would be a JavaScript object that looks something like this:

```
{
  nanoseconds: <something>, 
  // some other Timestamp properties
}
```

React does not know how to display this. Thus, try turning `message.date` into a string and then displaying it. This could involve many methods depending on how you want to implement it and format the final string. Many ways are provided in  [How do I convert a Firestore date/Timestamp to a JS Date()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247445/how-do-i-convert-a-firestore-date-timestamp-to-a-js-date) when accessing the time.

Comment: @NavalNehra Specifically, maybe look at this answer to see how to turn a Firebase Timestamp object into a string https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742504/8109320 Then, you can format it however you want.

Comment: thank for reply.
can you tell me about one more problem?
in firebase date is stored as ```February 18, 2023 at 9:45:13PM ``` but i want to store as ```21:45``` ie "hh:mm" 24h formate how can I do that?

Comment: I do't think you can modify what you see in the Firbease console, and you can't change how Firbease stores the timestamp. You can, however, turn `February 18, 2023 at 9:45:13PM` into `21:45` format when displaying it to the users. For example, if you have converted your `message.date` into a JavaScript `Date` object, you can then follow the method in this answer to turn it into a 24h format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17322318/8109320

Comment: yeahhh...
now its working fine. I add this one value-->

```
 chatTime: Timestamp.now().toDate().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {hour12: false})
```

Comment: Nice to hear that!