# How to convert utc time to 24 Hrs format in react native

Tags: react-native, date, momentjs, utc, date-conversion

I am new to react native ,I am trying to convert the given time "14:58" to utc in 24 hrs format.
I am using the code like this

```
     let currentDate = new Date();
     startDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
     startDate.setHours(startTime.split(":")[0]);
     startDate.setMinutes(startTime.split(":")[1]);

     let startUTC = moment(startDate).utc();
     console.log(startUTC)
```

I am getting the result like this "2023-03-23T09:28:58.638Z" which in 12 hrs clock.
Is there any way to convert this in 24 hr.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert time to 24 hours format in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788705/convert-time-to-24-hours-format-in-javascript)

Comment: No,given time "14:58" is converted to "2023-03-23T09:28:58.638Z",     I wanted this time to be conveted in 24 hrs in utc